# retrieving links in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VB code that can detect any word with http,.com,http,links in excel sheet?

Thanks in Advance

Code sample from comments

```
Sub ListLinks() 
  Dim aLinks As Variant aLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks) 
  If Not IsEmpty(aLinks) Then 
    Sheets.Add 
    For i = 1 To UBound(aLinks) 
      Cells(i, 1).Value = aLinks(i) 
    Next i 
  End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: Sub ListLinks()
    Dim aLinks As Variant
    aLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    If Not IsEmpty(aLinks) Then
        Sheets.Add
        For i = 1 To UBound(aLinks)
            Cells(i, 1).Value = aLinks(i)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Please modify your question to reflect your attempt and where you are failing.

Comment: The a bove code can retrive hayperlinks only ,I need tospecify exactly what to retrive such like any sentence ends with .com

Comment: @Yash ,I need VB Code that can retrive any cell has the following : Amazon, Eco-friendly, Environmentally-friendly, Eco friendly, Ecologically Friendly Also any cell that has  https, www, html

Comment: You can use `Instr` function in your code. But your question is not clear. Check how to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

```
  Sub search()
    Dim Regex
    Set Regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With Regex
      .Global = True
      .MultiLine = False
      .IgnoreCase = True
       .Pattern = "http|www|html|Amazon|(Eco|Environ).*friendly"
     End With

    Dim cell
    For Each cell In UsedRange.Cells
      If Regex.test(cell) Then
        cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        ' or save cell.value to sheet
        Count = Count + 1
      End If
    Next
    MsgBox Count & " found"
  End Sub
```

Comment: When I ran the a bove code I got  run time error 424 (Object required)

Comment: @maisam What version of excel ? Can you single step the program with debug/F8 and identify the line.

Comment: @maisam If you have put this code in a module rather than in a sheet then add the relevant sheet reference to Used.Range eg Sheets(1).UsedRange.Cells

Comment: I have added the sheet name and the code was run but it always resulted with 9 found and nothing is highlighted!any idea?

Comment: Add msgBox cell.address just before count = count +1 and it should give your the location of the match

Comment: Or try cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 rather than using the vb constant names.

Comment: How to inherit the opened sheet name

Comment: @Maisam Mohsen Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by inherit. Do you mean the sheet name that is create by Sheets.Add ?

Comment: I mean the abve code worked and got the defected cells highlighted but whenever I tried the code in different worksheet it give error because I need to change the sheet name manually.so I need a code that can read the worksheet name each time I open excel sheet

Comment: Maybe [activesheet.name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activesheet)